# Incorrect prefix key MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, mariadb

I have a problem creating a table with phpmyadmin, which gives me the following error:

> #1089 - Incorrect prefix key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn't support unique prefix keys

This is the query that I do:

```
CREATE TABLE `b2b`.`users` ( `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
 `surnames` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL ,
 `birthdate` DATE NOT NULL ,
 `drivingdoc` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
 `acdate` DATE NOT NULL ,
 `countrydoc` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
 `province` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
 `locality` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL ,
 `address` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL ,
 `number` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
 `flat` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
 `door` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
 `description` VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`(7))) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Using MariaDB in ubuntu minimal.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`(7))
```

You cannot use *part* of a number as a key, you have to use the whole thing. Also, specifying lengths for numeric types is useless at best, and damaging at worst.

Change to:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Answer (score 1):

That Primary Key syntax is nothing I've ever seen before. Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE `b2b`.`users` (
 `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   ....
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Or if you want

```
CREATE TABLE `b2b`.`users` (
 `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ....
 PRIMARY KEY (id) 
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have several errors in your sql, so try to find the difference with this sql

```
 CREATE TABLE  `b2b`.`users` ( `id` INT(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
 `surnames` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL ,
 `birthdate` DATE NOT NULL ,
 `drivingdoc` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
 `acdate` DATE NOT NULL ,
 `countrydoc` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
 `province` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
 `locality` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL ,
 `address` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL ,
 `number` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
 `flat` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
 `door` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
 `description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: The `(7)` is essentially useless in that context, too.

Comment: 'try to find the difference' is not helpful.